# Was the lecture in the classroom scene real or fictional?

Tags: young-frankenstein

Can anyone with medical background tell us if the lecture before the question session in *Young Frankenstein* was in fact a proper one or only fictional?

Comment: Well, I only *play* a doctor in real life, but even just a brief [Wiki visit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainstem#Midbrain) proves that yes, he's using the right terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from this image, taken for the [Wiki article for the Medulla Oblongata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medulla_oblongata), there is a midbrain, a pons and said medulla oblongata, all mentioned by Wilder's character.

[image]